# Can I search between name and name's date?

Tags: sql, mysql, join

I'm studying SQL and I wonder wheather that I can search the date of specific user.

Here is my database.

| name | password | email | comment | regdate | roll |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| guest1 | guest1 | guest1@email.tld | Hi I'm guest1 | 2021-02-03 23:23:43 | guest |
| guest2 | guest2 | guest2@email.tld | Hi I'm guest2 | 2021-02-04 08:23:43 | guest |
| admin | admin | admin@email.tld | Hi I'm admin | 2021-02-10 10:23:43 | admin |

I know between already and I can search like

```sql
SELECT *
FROM `objects`
WHERE (date_field BETWEEN '2021-02-03 23:23:43' AND '2021-02-10 10:23:43')
```

The Question is, can I search guest1.regdate instead of real date?
like this

```sql
SELECT *
FROM `objects`
WHERE (date_field BETWEEN `guest1.regdate` AND `admin.regdate`)
```

I tried to search about it, but I don't know how can I search, and how can I call it(guest1.regdate). specific row's specific column? it's strange.

Comment: Why is this tagged `[sql-injection]`?

Comment: You can likely do that if you can include `guest1` and `admin` in your query somehow via a `JOIN` or what have you.

Comment: @tadman I think here `guest1` and `admin` are values in a `name` field, in the same table.

Comment: Yeah this wouldn't be injection, this looks like "im sitting at the console ready to just enter code" .. no need to inject.  An Inject would be more like SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE USERNAME = USERNAME, but as its parsed the users from the front end form or something where its expecting a username they instead use a character to terminate like ; so instead it sends "SELECT * FROM USERS" .. now all the users are sent not just the selected user.  This is over simplified example but point is .. this is NOT sql-injection question due to it being back end only .

Comment: Try out, and expand upon `SELECT objects.* FROM objects JOIN (SELECT regdate date1 FROM objects WHERE name LIKE 'guest1') T1 JOIN (SELECT regdate date2 FROM objects WHERE name LIKE 'admin') T2 WHERE regdate BETWEEN date1 AND date2`

Comment: @tadman Cause This question is coming up from studying sql-injection. Actually, this is no need injection as other comment said. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: @Moige I tried the code and confirmed it works. It looks so complex. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your user table is called `appusers` and there is a unique key on the `name` field (if the data is not unique it may fail, in that case adding  `LIMIT 0,1` to the end of each subquery fixes it) this should work:

```sql
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `objects`
WHERE 
  date_field BETWEEN 
    ( select regdate from appusers where name = 'guest1') 
    AND 
    ( select regdate from appusers where name = 'admin')
```

Comment: SELECT *
FROM persons
WHERE regdate BETWEEN
(SELECT regdate FROM persons WHERE name = 'guest1')
AND
(SELECT regdate FROM persons WHERE name = 'admin');

It's working. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah that would be better than big useless joins, gj.